# How to apply a gradient to a rectangle in Highcharts

Tags: css, svg, highcharts, gradient

I want to add a rectangle to my Highcharts graph, in order to highlight the directions (hotter, colder). For that, I'd like to work with a gradient - from white to reddish, and from white to blue.

But I don't get how the [SVG gradient style](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) can be applied to the code used in Highcharts. Mine looks like this ([here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/6g5ttbfr/6/))

```
var rect = chart.renderer.rect(0, 90, 45, 273, 0).attr({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#009900',
    'stroke-width': 1
}).add();
```

How do I add the gradient style here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define gradient object and pass it to fill property:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g5ttbfr/8/)

```
 var gradient = {
         linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 400],
         stops: [
             [0, '#000'],
             [1, '#ff0000']
         ]
     };
     var rect = chart.renderer.rect(0, 90, 45, 273, 0).attr({
         fill: gradient,
         stroke: '#009900',
         'stroke-width': 1
     }).add();
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much! However, I didn't succeed in finding out what those four parameters stand for. Can you direct me to a doc which describes these? I have added a second, blue, rectangle ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/6g5ttbfr/9/)), and am confused about the settings I have to define.

Comment: @luftikus143 , check out this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors . This might help you

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It helped me, and I found a way, although I can't say that I understood how those four values function.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to define and add into the DOM like below.**

```
<defs>
<linearGradient id="linear" y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%">
<stop stop-color="#05a" offset="0%">
<stop stop-color="#a55" offset="50%">
<stop stop-color="#0a5" offset="100%">
</linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect stroke-width="1" stroke="#009900" fill="url(#linear)" height="273" width="45" y="90" x="0">
```

Reference: http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-linear-gradients/

Comment: Yes, that's what I say in the above mentioned documentation as well. But that won't work with the use of Highcharts. The question for me is how to combine the use of SVG and Highcharts `chart.renderer.rect`. There is a list of attributes possible to attach; but what's the way to use a gradient here?